# How to change the border color of a disabled entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter, colors

I'm building a calculator program and want to change the border color of my entry widget when it's in a disabled state. I tried doing the highlightcolor function but it just added a new border to the one I already had (the borderwidth). Here's what I have so far:

```
e = Entry(root, width=30, borderwidth=5, font=calFont) 
e.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3, padx=5, pady=5, ipady=3)

e.config(state='disabled', disabledforeground='white')
```

Comment: Then delete the original border before disabling the widget.

Comment: But I like the original border because it looks more appealing. They are different borders.

Comment: I just told you how to fix your problem. You need to delete the original border if you don't want two borders.

Comment: I want to change the color of it

Comment: How about changing the color and then disabling the widget

Comment: Okay Okay, either I didn't phrase the question correctly in which case I'm sorry or you're not understanding me. The goal that I'm trying to achieve is to change the color of the border in my entry widget that has the borderwidth=5. I don't know how to do that. You can copy my code and see what I'm talking about.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for this solution. `highlightthickness` specifies the `borderwidth` in combination with `highlightbackground` and `highlightcolor` you can define a specific color.

This is not a guide on how to design your app, just what it might look like:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def showSmth():
    global state
    if state is True:
        btn.configure(text="Disabled")
        ent.config(state=DISABLED, highlightcolor="green", highlightbackground="green")
        state = False
    else:
        btn.configure(text="Enabled")
        ent.config(state=NORMAL, highlightcolor="blue", highlightbackground="blue")
        state = True


state = True

ent = Entry(root, bg="yellow", highlightthickness=5, highlightcolor="blue", highlightbackground="blue")
ent.pack()

btn = Button(root, text="Enabled", command=showSmth)
btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```